# Cómo puedo hacer que el dropdown menú se reduzca o expanda según lo seleccionado? Por ejemplo, como el dropdown menú de la barra de búsqueda de Amazon

Tags: javascript, css, select, dropdown, width

Tengo un dropdown menu en HTML el cual me gustaría que su ancho se ajuste según el contenido de la opción seleccionada.

```
    <div id="searchDrop" class="nav-search">
        <select onchange="changeWidth()" class="nav-search-dropdown searchSelect nav-progressive-attrubute nav-progressive-search-dropdown" id="searchDropdownBox" title="Search in">
            <option value="search-alias=Todas">Todas las Categorías</option>
            <option value="search-alias=Accesorios">Accesorios</option>
            <option value="search-alias=mobile-apps">Apps &amp; Games</option>
            <option value="search-alias=arte">Arte</option>
            <option value="search-alias=audiolibros"> Audiolibros</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

He intentado con Javascript de la siguiente forma, sin embargo, no es precisa.

```
let changeWidth = () => {
  let l = (document.getElementById("searchDrop").style.width =
    document.getElementById("searchDropdownBox").options[
      document.getElementById("searchDropdownBox").selectedIndex
    ].text.length);

  document.getElementById("searchDrop").style.width = l * 10 + "px";
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Un `select` cuenta con 2 partes en su "display": El texto seleccionado y una punta de flecha.

Para calcular el ancho de un texto, podemos usar la siguiente técnica:

- Copiar el texto seleccionado
- Copiar los estilos del select usando `getComputedStyle`, nos interesa especialmente el `font-size` y `font-family`, porque evidentemente el tamaño del texto depende de esas 2 variables
- Creamos un div auxiliar
- Colocamos el texto seleccionado
- Medimos el width del div
- Borramos el div auxiliar

Para el caso de la flecha hacia abajo, es bastante más complejo, así que para no complicar el asunto vamos a asumir que mide siempre `24px` de ancho. Entonces el `width` será de `width_div_aux + 24px`

Demo:

```js
const select = document.getElementById('searchDropdownBox');
select.addEventListener("change",changeWidth);

function changeWidth(){
  const div_aux = document.createElement("div");
  const estilo = getComputedStyle(select); //obtenemos los estilos del select

  div_aux.innerText = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text; //obtenemos el texto seleccionado
  
  document.body.appendChild(div_aux);
  
  //copiamos los estilos
  div_aux.style.fontSize = estilo.fontSize;
  div_aux.style.fontFamily = estilo.fontFamily;
  div_aux.style.display ="inline-block";

  //obtenemos el ancho del div auxiliar
  const width = getComputedStyle(div_aux).width;


  select.style.width=`calc(${width} + 24px)`;
  div_aux.remove(); //eliminamos el width
}
```

```html
<select id="searchDropdownBox" title="Search in">
    <option value="search-alias=Todas">Todas las Categorías</option>
    <option value="search-alias=Accesorios">Accesorios</option>
    <option value="search-alias=mobile-apps">Apps &amp; Games</option>
    <option value="search-alias=arte">Arte</option>
    <option value="search-alias=audiolibros"> Audiolibros</option>
</select>
```